# Why Pattern is final?

Tags: java, class, final

I wont try to extends a Pattern because we can't (I will wrap), but I would like to know why Pattern class is final ?

I mean this class could be extended for a largest use but they did the choice to make it final. Why ?

If i ask it, it is more in a technical (curious ?) way than in a "java is so bad" way.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please clarify and elaborate a bit. Not my down-vote by the way. I will await your response before down-voting.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Seems like the OP just wants to know the reasoning behind why the `Pattern` is declared `final` in Java.  Seems reasonable enough to me...

Comment: @TimPote: I understand that, but I want to understand the impetus behind the question. Why is he trying to extend it in the first place? It smells kludgy to me, and likely there's a better way. Anyone can state what has been stated in the answer by Matt, but that doesn't get us to why he's trying to do this in the first place. There's a deeper question that he's not asking.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Agreed, sounds like an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) overall.

Comment: @TimPote: a wonderful paradigm, thanks! I will definitely borrow this idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's `final` specifically to *prevent* you from extending it, because it is not designed to be subclassed. [`Pattern` instances are immutable and thread-safe](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), neither of which would be guaranteed if you created your own subclass of `Pattern`.

- [Why is the java.util.Scanner class declared 'final'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776940/why-is-the-java-util-scanner-class-declared-final?rq=1)
- [Why is String class declared final in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068804/why-is-string-final-in-java)
- And of course, the all-important *Effective Java* quote:

  > #### [Item 17: Design and document for inheritance or else prohibit it](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/9780137150021/classes-and-interfaces/ch04lev1sec5)

Comment: Ok I see thanks to your links. By extending we could overwrite an optimised method and break java performances

Comment: @souf what? No, it's not just a question of performance. You could break _correctness!_